# JavaScriptで絵文字の正確な長さを取得する

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox

JavaScriptで絵文字の正確な長さを取得したいのですが、うまくいきません。
(蛇の絵文字)は1文字なので 1 を期待しているのですが、2 が 返ってきてしまいます。
Firefox, Node.js, io.js などいろいろなもので試しましたが、やはり 2 が返ってきています。
どうすれば、正確な長さを取得できるのでしょうか?

```
var my_string = ""; // 蛇の絵文字
var str_length = my_string.length;
console.log(str_length); // 2
```

Comment: 回答はしたものの、自分の持っている全ての環境で "" の字が豆腐になるので、コードでしか正体がわからない悲しさ・・・

Answer (score 8, accepted):

絵文字はサロゲートペアと呼ばれる<del>領域に格納されています</del>代用符号を用いた2個組の文字で構成されます。
サロゲートペアを間引いた数が可視文字の数となります。

```
var my_string = "";
var str_length = my_string.length - (my_string.split(/[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g).length - 1);
print(str_length); // 1
```

**追記**

ちょっと改良

```
var my_string = "";
var str_length = my_string.length - (my_string.match(/[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g)||[]).length;
print(str_length); // 1
```

Comment: 細かい突っ込みをすると、サロゲートペアは"領域"ではなく"代用符号位置(surrogate code point)という符号単位(code unit)"の2個組を意味します。「絵文字は、UTF-16だとサロゲートペアとして表現される／しなければならない符号位置(code point)に格納されている」が正しい表現でしょうか。（まだるっこしい）

Comment: サロゲートペアの後半以外の文字数を数えたらシンプルかなと思いました。 `my_string.match(/[^\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g).length`

Comment: それだとサロゲートペア以外が無い場合にエラーになるかと。

Comment: あぁ空文字の時にnullになるんでしたっけ。
(my_string.match(/[^\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g) || []).length

Answer (score 9):

`String.prototype[@@iterator]`　はサロゲートペアが考慮されているので、
それを内部で使用している関数など使えば取得できます。

```
Array.from("野家").length
// => 3
```

Answer (score 6):

UTF-16 では、[サロゲートペア](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#.E3.82.B5.E3.83.AD.E3.82.B2.E3.83.BC.E3.83.88.E3.83.9A.E3.82.A2)を使う文字、例えば件の "" は４バイトの表現となり、 `length` プロパティでは 2 文字であると認識されてしまいます。

*`toHexUnicode()`: 文字コードを調べる関数*:

```js
function toHexUnicode( str) {
    var codes = "";
    for ( i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var codeHex = str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16).toUpperCase();
        codes = codes + "U+" + codeHex;
    }
    return codes;
}
```

この関数を使って調べると、"" が4バイトであることが分かります。

```js
toHexUnicode("")
// => "U+D83DU+DC0D"
```

対策ですが、この際、文字列に新しいプロパティを定義してしまってはどうでしょうか。

```js
String.prototype.__defineGetter__("length_unicode", function() {
  var i = 0, len = this.length, result = 0;
  while (i < len) {
    result++;
    var x = this.charCodeAt(i++);
    if (0xD800 <= x && x < 0xDC00) i++;
  }
  return result;
});
```

`length_unicode` のテスト:

```js
my_string.length
// => 2
my_string.length_unicode
// => 1
```

---

文字数のカウントの仕方については、、以下の記事を参考にしました。同様のことは、参考リンク中の [js-codepoints](https://github.com/dankogai/js-codepoints) ライブラリで可能です。

- [Twitter時代の文字の数え方](http://blog.unfindable.net/archives/2728), 配電盤
- [javascript - でBMP以外のUnicode文字をきちんと扱う](http://blog.livedoor.jp/dankogai/archives/51861512.html), 404 Blog Not Found

記事にあるとおり、"野家"なども問題になるんですね。

```js
toHexUnicode("")
// => "U+D842U+DFB7"
toHexUnicode("野家")
// => "U+D842U+DFB7U+91CEU+5BB6"
"野家".length_unicode
// => 3
"野家".length
// => 4
```

Answer (score 5):

ES6だと

```
str_length = [...my_string].length
```

で取れます。

Answer (score 5):

絵文字の中には国コードの組み合わせた国旗、バリエーションセレクターが後ろに続く異体字 (バリアント)、肌色を変える修飾子が続くもの (Unicode 8.0 で導入予定) など、2つのコードポイントで構成されるものもあるので、それらも考慮する必要がある場合、拡張書記素クラスターに対応したライブラリが必要になります。grapheme-breaker のコードの例を示します。

```
var GraphemeBreaker = require('grapheme-breaker');

// 日本の国旗
// http://www.taishukan.co.jp/kokugo/webkoku/series003_11.html
var c = String.fromCodePoint(0x1F1EF, 0x1F1F5);
console.log(c);

// バリアント
// http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/StandardizedVariants.html
var c2 = String.fromCodePoint(0x267F, 0xFE0F);
console.log(c2);

// Unicode 8.0 で対応予定
// VI 型の肌色の少年
// http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/tr51-2.html#Diversity
// var c3 = String.fromCodePoint(0x1F466, 0x1F3FF);
// console.log(c3);

var str = c + c2;
// 拡張書記素クラスターの数
console.log(GraphemeBreaker.countBreaks(str));

var length = str.length;
var previous = 0;
var current = 0;

while (current < length) {
    previous = current;
    current = GraphemeBreaker.nextBreak(str, previous);
    console.log(str.slice(previous, current));
}
```

文字数のバリデーションを扱う際に、1つの拡張書記素クラスターを構成する要素数の上限がないことを考慮する必要があります。

```
var c = "\u267F" + "\uFE0F".repeat(10000);
console.log(1 === GraphemeBreaker.countBreaks(c));
```

Chrome や Intl を有効にした node/iojs であれば、[Intl.v8BreakIterator](https://code.google.com/p/v8-i18n/wiki/BreakIterator) を使うことができます。

```
var c = String.fromCodePoint(0x1F1EF, 0x1F1F5);
var c2 = String.fromCodePoint(0x267F, 0xFE0F);
var str = c + c2;

console.log(2 === graphemeLength(str, ['ja-JP']));

function graphemeLength(str, locales)
{
    var it = new Intl.v8BreakIterator(locales, {type: 'character'});
    it.adoptText(str);

    var length = 0;
    var previous = 0;
    var current = it.first();

    while (current !== -1) {

        current = it.next();

        if (current === -1) {
            break;
        }

        previous = current;
        ++length;
    }

    return length;
}
```